# Creating a dynamic textfield inside a grdiview

Tags: jquery, gridview, dynamic, yii, textfield

```
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm('','post',array('id'=>'base-si-received-item-form'));?>
<?php 
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'base-si-received-item-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>BaseRefSiDetails::model()->search(),
        //'filter'=>$searchModel,
        'columns'=>array(       
            array(
                'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
                'id'=>'base-si-received-item-id',       
                'selectableRows'=>2, // multiple rows can be selected
            ),                  
            array(
                'name'=>'unit',
                'header'=>'unit',
                'type'=>'raw',
                'value'=>'CHtml::textField(BaseSiReceivedItem::model()->quantity_received,"",array("id"=>"received_quantity","name"=>"quantity_received"))',
            ),
            array(
                'name'=>'unit',
                'header'=>'unit',
                'type'=>'raw',
                'value'=>'CHtml::dropDownlist(BaseSiReceivedItem::model()->unit,"unit",array("pc"=>"pc","box"=>"box"))'
            ),
            array(
                'name'=>'unit_cost',
                'header'=>'unit cost',
                'type'=>'raw',
                'value'=>'CHtml::textField(BaseSiReceivedItem::model()->unit_cost,"",array("id"=>"unit_cost"))',
            ),
            array(
                'name'=>'total_cost',
                'header'=>'total cost',
                'type'=>'raw',
                'value'=>'CHtml::textField(BaseSiReceivedItem::model()->total_cost,"",array("id"=>"total_cost","readonly"=>"readonly"))',
            ),
        )
    )
?>
```

I have a problem on my **gridview** .
What I need to do is, when input a number of quantity received and unit cost, the price will automatically be shown on total cost.
I have a **jquery** script to do that.
 
My problem is the only first row are executing the codes :

Here is my **jquery**:

```
 $(document).ready( function(){
     $("#unit_cost").keyup(function() {        
         $("#total_cost").val($("#unit_cost").val() * $("#received_quantity").val());        
     });    
 });
```

Comment: Your ids are repeating. Use a class instead an it should work.

Comment: i used what you said and what happened is when input numbers on quan received and unit cost all of the total cost will have the same number

Answer (score 1):

As @Örs said, change your ids to classes. Also the [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) of the operation should be a row as follows:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $(".unit_cost").keyup(function(){
        var tr=$(this).closest('tr');
        $(".total_cost",tr).val($(".unit_cost",tr).val() * $(".received_quantity",tr).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: change the `var tr=this.closest('tr');` to `var tr=$(this).closest('tr')`